# Is it ok if I use all pins on non AC connector for AC

Tags: pcb-design, ac, connector, hardware

I intend to use non AC connector [Hirose DH40](https://www.hirose.com/product/p/CL0684-4189-3-51?lang=en) and DH37 for single AC line (230VAC).

Connector single pin is rated 30V 0.3A. They did also did a test for 100VAC for 1 min.

Plan is to use two connectors and all 10 pins on both connectors just for single AC line (so 20 pins on a single AC line).

I did a test the connectors with load for several hours and it works. 
My main concern now is safety and certificates.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The datasheet clearly states that it is rated for 30 V AC or DC. If you exceed this rating or use AC then you are on your own. You certainly couldn't certify a device knowingly using a component operating outside the manufacturer's ratings.

Answer (score 1):

So you're proposing to have all pins common on each connector, so each connector sees no voltage between pins (except that caused by internal resistance)

I don't see a problem with that so long as you treat the entire connector as being potentially live (don't rely on any part of the connector for electrical insulation)

This precision connector seems an odd choice, I would consider ordinary metal connectors like those used on 9V batteries etc...

Comment: Yes - all connector pins are connected on ONLY one AC line (L on N).

Comment: I need a mezzanine board to board connector with 2.5 or 3.5 distance only one pin is needed. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: keystone 261, 269 as above (if 3mm is acceptable)